# subversion client 1.7 file externals update error

Tags: svn

I have come across an error using `svn update` on a working copy folder with single file svn:externals. I wonder if there is a work-around for this, if I am doing something wrong, or if this is a bug in the client 1.7.x of subversion.

The error occurs when calling `svn update` using subversion 1.7.5 (tried TortoiseSvn 1.7.7 and slikSvn 1.7.5) on a folder that has single file `svn:externals`. I'm tempted to say it's a bug in the subversion client, because the update does indeed occur, but it says it fails.

For reference, the server side uses a very old version (1.1.4 [r13838]), but from what I know externals is a client "feature" so an old server should not be a problem. Besides, this workes well using subversion 1.6.x (client).

This is the scenario I observe:

1. Checkout a project (that has single file `svn:externals`)

   ```
   svn checkout http://my/repo/projects/proj1 proj1
   ```
2. Browsing to the folder in my working copy with single file `svn:externals`. E.g.

   ```
   myFile.txt http://my/repo/components/comp1/myFile.txt
   ```
3. Executing `svn update` and I get the following output:

```
Fetching external item into 'trunk\proj1\source\myFile.txt':
: warning: W160016: Failure opening 
'/components/comp1/myFile.txt/myFile.txt'
```

If change the `svn:externals` so that the local file has a different name, like below:

```
my_file.txt http://my/repo/components/comp1/myFile.txt
```

Then the error message in 3. becomes as below, so the the file after the last forward slash ('/') is the local version of the file.

```
Fetching external item into 'trunk\proj1\source\myFile.txt':
: warning: W160016: Failure opening '/components/comp1/myFile.txt/my_file.txt'
```

Comment: I you think it's a bug, write to users@subversion.apache.org . If you are not sure it's a bug, you may ask at #svn IRC channel at freenode.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looking more around the web, I've found a similar issue reported to users@subversion.apache.org: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.user/110121 from May 7th 2012, but I could not find any responses.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Is it reproducible with SVNKit (pure Java SVN implementation)? Are URLs http://my/repo/components/comp1/myFile.txt and http://my/repo/projects/proj1 from the same repository ("svn info" would be helpful)? Is it reproducible if you use the following value instead: "http://my/repo/components/comp1/myFile.txt my_file.txt" (new externals format)?

Comment: The repository root is the same for both my/repo/components/comp1/myFile.txt and my/repo/projects/proj1. 

I changed the `svn:externals` format to "repo/url/to/myFile.txt local_name.txt", but I still get the same 'failure opening' error message.

Comment: Here's the output of `svn --version`: 
_svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830)_
_compiled Jun 27 2012, 14:12:04_

Comment: This seems to be related to the svn server version used. If I created a test svn server (version 1.7.x) and the problem disappeared. I'm still puzzled why client 1.7.x suddently complaints about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in the subversion client. See http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4224 for details: it has been fixed in subversion 1.7.7.

As pointed out in the question, fortunately it doesn't affect the function - the local file is still updated to match the external one, but you get the spurious error messages shown.